# how to filter data in google sheets based on Dropdown value

Tags: google-sheets

I want to view data based on the dropdown value of Column A1. i.e if "absolute" option is selected from the dropdown list then view 1 should be visible and if "% View" option is selected then view 2
should be visible

***Problem Statement:***
[image]

Comment: Simply try `=ArrayFormula(IF(A2="Absolute",C2:D10,F2:G10))` adjust ranges with your range.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Harun24HR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833853/how-to-filter-data-in-google-sheets-based-on-dropdown-value#comment119900319_67833853):

Simply try `=ArrayFormula(IF(A2="Absolute",C2:D10,F2:G10))` adjust ranges with your range.